# Is the third RCA connector for video?

Tags: audio

Sorry for the ignorance, but I need an adapter from two RCA audio jack to the 3.5 jack. However, looking back on my projector I see three RCA ports. Is the third one for video?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a legend with details:

http://www.camerahacker.com/AV_Cable/RCA_Pin-Out.html

If this is what you have, then the yellow jacket RCA is video, the red is audio right channel, while the white is audio left channel.